Consuming SOAP with Spring boot digital certificate
I created the following structure to consume a SOAP web service that uses a digital certificate
My configuration is like this:
@Bean
public SSLContext sslContext() throws Exception {
    String keystorePassword = senhaArquivoJKS; 
    String keyPassword = senhaChaveJKS; 

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    try (InputStream keyStoreStream = new FileInputStream(caminhoArquivoJKS)) {
        keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        log.error(caminhoArquivoJKS);
        return createDefaultSSLContext();
    }

    try
       
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyPassword.toCharArray())
                .build();
        
        
        
        

        for (String alias : Collections.list(keyStore.aliases())) {
            log.info("Alias no keystore: " + alias);
            log.info(" Certificado: " + keyStore.getCertificate(alias));
        }
        return sslContext;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        return createDefaultSSLContext();
    } 
}   




@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient(SSLContext sslContext) {
    Header contentTypeHeader = new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");


    return HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext != null ? sslContext : createDefaultSSLContext())
            .setDefaultHeaders(Collections.singletonList(contentTypeHeader))
            .addInterceptorFirst(new HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor())
            .build();
}   

                                                                                                    @Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.system.ws");
    //marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(Collections.singletonMap(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true));
    return marshaller;
}



@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller, CloseableHttpClient httpClient) {
    //HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender(httpClient);
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
     webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(new HttpComponentsMessageSender(httpClient));
    webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[]{new SoapLoggingInterceptor()});

    return webServiceTemplate;
}              

When execute in my service Class  the server just return 400 Bad Request.
Has anyone had this problem? Is there an error in my configuration?
I've already checked the request envelope and headers and haven't identified any problems with them.
